# Seeking to streamline message system in my engine (C++)

Tags: c++, messaging

So been building up my own custom engine, and one core bit of it is a message system to keep all the systems disconnected.

As it currently stands I have it take in a pointer to every other system, and then during their creation they register with the message system for what they want to receive.

The problem is the message system right now knows exactly what each system is, and I would like to simplify that.

My goal is to have any system sign up for messages, without the message system needing to care about the type of system. I thought about adding a "message class" parent class wrapper to put around every system, but that feels more like a jury rig then a fix, and I would like to avoid having layers of class wrappers.

Anyone have any thoughts how to simply this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually messaging systems work by having a message receiving interface that other classes can implement if they want to receive messages. It can be something simple like this:

```
class MessageHandler {
    public:
        MessageHandler();
        ~MessageHandler();

        virtual void MessageHandler::handleMessage(MessageType msg, MessageSender* msgSender, void* msgData) = 0;
};
```

You can make any class be able to receive messages by inheriting from this base class and implementing the above method.

You can make a `MessageDispatcher` object that allows any object to register itself with the dispatcher. Something like this:

```
class MessageDispatcher {
    public:
        MessageDispatcher();
        ~MessageDispatcher();

        RegisterMessageHandler(MessageHandler* newHandler, MessageType msg);
        DispatchMessage(MessageType msg, MessageSender* msgSender, void* msgData);
};
```

Generally, the MessageDispatcher is a singleton, though it's certainly possible to have different dispatchers for different parts of your system, if that would be more efficient or appropriate. In any case, when you create any object that you want to be able to receive messages, you simply call:

```
msgDispatcher.RegisterMessageHandler(this, whateverMessage, msgData);
```

And when you have a message you want to send, the sender can do this:

```
msgDispatcher.DispatchMessage(whateverMessage, this, msgData);
```

With this system, any object can sign up for messages without knowing or caring about any of the other objects types or systems. (Though they will have to agree on what data goes with what message type so they can communicate.)

Comment: Thanks for a clear response. Was hoping to avoid making a MessageHandler base class, but if that is a common method used I might as well stick with it.

(Full disclosure, I learned the basics of programming from college, but been self taught since, have little traction for what is good or bad habits.)